# Reditect from handle function in Hooks.js , SvelteKit

Tags: redirect, svelte, sveltekit

I tried this solution from StackOverflow and some other solutions
[Redirecting from exported handle hook in sveltekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71360354/redirecting-from-exported-handle-hook-in-sveltekit)

I tried to redirect after authentication from the handle function inside hooks.js. I tried to like this

```
 return  response.redirect(event.url.origin+"/login2", 303);
```

but this gives me an error

```
500
TypeError: response.redirect is not a functionat Object.handle (/mnt/golang/vscode Web/svelteKit/s16JWT/src/hooks.ts:48:30)at async respond (file:///mnt/golang/vscode%20Web/svelteKit/s16JWT/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:2685:20)at async file:///mnt/golang/vscode%20Web/svelteKit/s16JWT/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:299:24
```

i tried in some other methods in some other places inside my code base , only place i could redirect from `<script context="module"></script>` or `<script></script>` using **goto()** method or **header redirect**. help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I would use if I am setting up a redirect header with a link.

```
export const handle: Handle = async({event, resolve})=>{
 return new Response('Redirect', {status: 303, headers: { Location: '/login' }})
}
```

Basically you are sending a custom response with new custom headers.

There's no need to prepend an origin, though. I am sure you get that from the load function of the context module.

Comment: did it work for you ,  it is showing "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: @sk shahriar ahmed raka Yes I just checked it out on my local device, and it seems to work. Maybe you are calling it from another function?

Comment: can you provide me your sample code, in github repo

Answer (score 1):

I've run in to issues with redirect from handler a few times. if youve set other headers - cookies - then you might run in to problems redirecting.

Comment: now i am trying in another way , i check cookie from getSession()  if cookie is not valid it will sent value in return , i catch the value in load function from <script context="module"> using session , and redirect it from there .  how secure is this solution ??